# CSS Rounded corners in Tabs little issue

Tags: css, rounded-corners

I have this code http://jsfiddle.net/Kbzgd/ what i'm trying to do is on the top right corner it have the rounded effect aswell...

But if i remove the border-bottom and add that border to the content like border-top, the active tab gets that border on the bottom, and i don't want that =\

I want it like this but with the rounded corner on the top right corner, is possible ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `border-top-right-radius: 5px` on `.tab_content_container`

After a little more fiddling I added this:

```
border-top-right-radius: 6px;
border-top: 1px solid #CCC;
position: relative;
top: -1px;
z-index: -10;
```

So the right corner looks a little nicer. An alternative is to use `box-shadow: 0 -1px 0 0 #CCC` (shadow above div) instead of the `border-top` and `top` values.

Edit: After some more editing I got rid of little bit sticking out (you'll see if you look carefully with the above couple examples).

All you have to do is remove the border on the ul (the border/shadow from the div works fine, as long as you set its `z-index` behind the ul). Note that when you move the border it shifts a bit, so you could set `position: relative; top: 1px;` back on the ul.

I gave multiple options because I don't know if anything will conflict with the rest of your code.

Here's my final CSS:

```
ul.tabs {
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0); /*this is an alternative which sets the border to be transparent*/
    float: left; 
    height: 29px; 
    list-style: none; 
    margin: 0; 
    padding: 0; 
    width: 100%;
}

.tab_content_container {
    background: #fff;
    border-radius: 0 0 5px 5px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc; border-top: none;
    clear: both; 
    float: left; 
    width: 100%; 
    border-top-right-radius: 6px;
    /*border-top: 1px solid #CCC;
    /*top: -1px; again some alternatives*/
    position: relative;
    z-index: -10;
    box-shadow: 0 -1px 0 0 #CCC
}
```

Comment: Thanks Raeki, with your code i just edited the width of the ul.tabs to  width: 99%; and it looks perfect now !

Comment: Haha that was bugging me too - I added an alternative fix you could take a look at that too. Happy coding!

Comment: Hmmm in the http://jsfiddle.net looks ok but in my web site it hides the content, the z-index is hidding it...

Comment: The link didn't work properly, but you could set the z-index to be higher (like -1), or set the z-index of the ul higher (looks like that'd be a better option)

Comment: I have redone this and it works better this way http://jsfiddle.net/Kbzgd/19/ but i have a sligtly little bug.
If you look at the left tab, there is a small white space ( a white pixel ) its nothing major, but some people may notice lol, is there a way to fix it ? lol

Comment: I can't think of an easy way; you would use borders or box shadows for any outline effect, but there's no way you could layer it so that you could have an extra pixel sticking out. I suppose you could lower all the tabs a pixel so it would look connected, I'm playing around with it so I'll let you know if I figure something out.

Comment: I finally found a solution http://jsfiddle.net/c8Xxu/ damn this was getting frustrating lool i was doing some other stuff and thinked about it and tried and tried and tried and finally did it..

it still have that small white pixel on the left, but that i can't figure how to remove whithout the code being so uglyyyy

Comment: I id'd the div 'content' and added this code: `.content {
    border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
    position: relative;
    top: -1px;
    z-index: -10;
}` and changed removed the border from `ul.tabHolder li`. If there are "hiding" problems with the content, change the `z-index` back to 0 and set the `z-index` of `xmenu` higher (remember, z-index only applies to positioned elements, so you'll also have to add a `position: relative` to it)

Answer (score 1):

Here: http://jsfiddle.net/2CVNj/
Added a new div around the tabs to use the [`overflow: auto` solution](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/clearing.html) to clear the floats, and then moved the border on top of the content and fiddled with some z-indexes. Works nicely.